# Объявление строки в классе

Tags: классы, c++

Есть класс, в котором нужно определить и инициализировать строку.
Я так понял что в классах можно определять только интовые переменные к тому же статические и константы.

```
class Background:public environment
{ 
public: static const char* str_to_bckgrnd="Images/environment/33.png";

}AS;
```

ошибка следующая : `only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class`

почему подобная конструкция не допускается?и как можно по другому поступить со строкой?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А почему бы вам не сделать то, что просит компилятор: вынести инициализацию строки изнутри декларации класса?

```
class Background : public environment
{ 
public:
    static const char* str_to_bckgrnd;
} AS;

const char* Background::str_to_bckgrnd="Images/environment/33.png";
```

[Проверка](http://ideone.com/zLNyLm).

Comment: ого) неловко получилось. спасибо

Comment: @Dexter384: не переживайте сильно: синтаксис C++ — один из самых запутанных и нелогичных.