# Динамический трехмерный массив через векторы

Tags: массивы, c++

здравствуйте.мне нужно создать динамический трехмерный массив. дело в том что я не знаю размеров массива в начале. и узнаю их в позже в одной из функций.и в одной из этих же функции мне нужно задать значения элементам этого массива.я думаю делать через вектора. у меня есть класс, в котором я объявляю трехмерный  вектор

```
 class Base
    {
    private:
    static std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char> > > mas;
    static void func1();
    static void func2();
...
    }
```

а в одной из функций  как узнаю размер массива изменяю его через resize . 
т.е. для одного измерения так делаю(для примера)

```
int nj=14;
mas.resize(nj);
```

вообще делать через resize подходит для данной задачи? у меня выходит такая ошибка:

```
Error   194 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > environment::mas" (?mas@environment@@2V?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@A)  C:\Users\jh\Desktop\App.obj MyFirstApp

Error   195 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: @Dexter384, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

- Да, через resize именно то, что надо. Но не забудьте поменять размер и вложенных массивов тоже.
- Нет, ошибка линковки не из-за resize. Дайте полный текст ошибки.

У вас уже была похожая проблема: [Объявление строки в классе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/267936/). Эта решается так же.

**Обновление**

Вот вам [документация с примерами](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static).

Comment: Обновил пост с полной ошибкой

Comment: так там ошибка в том, что я не вынес инициализацию из строки. а здесь что нужно вынести?

Comment: Спасибо) Оказалось, что в классе я просто объявлял вектор, а нужно было его проинициализировать его 

    std::vector<unsigned char> environment::mas;

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка потому что, объект статического класса не создается, соответственно не создаётся переменная "mas", а только неинициализированная ссылка на него, поэтому нужно продублировать в спипишнике

```
static std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char> > > Base::mas;
```